# Cant hit my API, have i the wrong URL?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, jersey-2.0

I have a Dynamic Java Web project with Jersey libs called myApi...

The Apache Tomcat server starts ok ... i get HTTP 404 status no mattr what url i enter.
I have a  Web.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myApi</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <!-- The package where your resource classes are -->
        <param-value>WS</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myApi</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

A java class...

```
package ws;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;

@Path("test")
public class Connect {
    @GET
    @Path("test")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello(){
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your web.xml you list the jersey packages as `WS` (uppercase) but your java class is in package `ws` (lowercase).  Maybe the problem?  Or part of the problem anyway.

Comment: thx, i changed to lowercase ws but still get error. i get http404 even if i hit localhost